# Как получить URL картинки из браузера?

Tags: android, веб-программирование, google-chrome, webview

Есть приложение, в котором есть кнопка и **EditText**, по нажатию на которую необходимо вывести запрос, который будет браться из **EditText**, в google, и не просто в google, а в google **картинки**, далее пользователь тыкает на картинку и браузер возвращает ему URL картинки.

Я не силён в познаниях HTML и запросов, но моих мозгов достаточно, чтобы взять и распарсить самому какой-нибудь запрос в разделе картинок, поэтому я с этим моментом справился, необходимо вводить нечто наподобие:

```
https://www.google.ru/search?q=images&newwindow=1&biw=1680&bih=949&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Y4b1VN34BoHAUoSFhJgI&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ
```

В принципе, если взглянуть, то понятно, где находится сам запрос, и какое разрешение выставлено в поиске, тут ничего трудного, но меня волнует вопрос, как потом по нажатию на картинку вернуть её URL. У меня лишь 2 мысли: либо использовать [WebChromeClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html), либо реализовывать WebView и уже пытаться что-то делать там.

Также заранее благодарю за ответы и хотелось бы ещё спросить, где можно почитать про запросы и как они формируются, чтобы получше понять, что значат все эти префиксы в ссылке, описанной выше и какие ещё можно использовать для более точного поиска. Спасибо!

**Обновление**

Также хотелось добавить, что даже с выставленным разрешением в поиске картинки всё равно выводятся в неотсортированном виде или браузер выводит картинки, которые предназначены для вывода в поисковик, но сам браузер подразумевает, что эти картинки имеют нужное разрешение, но находятся на сайте?

На данный момент получилось самому нарыть кое-какой способ, который связан с WebView. Попробую реализовать его, если получится, то дам ответ тут.

Comment: Нашёл решение, но оно ООООЧЕНЬ заковыристое. Необходимо всё сделать аккуратно и убедиться в полной работоспособности. Также всё осложняется тем, что даже у Google Chrome с этим не всё в порядке, т.е. он выдаёт неправильные ответы, а это уже косяк Google, под неправильными ответами я понимаю то, что вместо Uri, в некоторых случаях, он может вернуть совсем другое.

Comment: Мне кажется, вам лучше воспользоваться [google custom search api](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/customsearch/v1) и не надо будет ничего парсить. Браузер тоже не нужен

Comment: Обязательно попробую реализовать и google custome search api, но у меня всё-таки получилось моим методом, работает 100%, если пользователь нажал на картинку, т.е. выбрал нужную. Не совсем понятно, как без браузера мне реализовать всё это, ведь пользователь сам должен выбрать нужное ему...

Comment: Решение было найдено, но писать в ответе слишком много, легче статью посветить. Скажу лишь, что это реализуется через WebView и WebView.getHitTestResult(), но там тоже есть свои подвохи, т.к., вместо URL картинки, можно получить совсем другой результат